# Case classes match on type

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

If I try to match a variable on its type, like in the code below:

```
object CaseClassesApp extends App {

  sealed trait A{}
  final case class B() extends A{} 
  final case class C() extends A{}

  def tryMatch(x: Any): String = x match {
    case B => "It's a B!"
    case C => "It's a C!"
    case _ => "nope"
  }

  var testB = new B()
  print(tryMatch(testB))
}
```

Shouldn't it give me "It's a B!"? Why do I receive a "nope" instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to type match, you can implement it by modifying your code just a little.

```
def tryMatch(x: Any): String = x match {
  case b:B => "It's a B!"
  case c:C => "It's a C!"
  case _ => "nope"
}
```

Comment: Since you aren't using the values you should be able to replace `b:B` with `_:B` (Same for `c`).

Comment: @sedulam I have pasted the modified code into my IDE, it works. Maybe the link http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html  is helpful and search "Typed patterns" in the html

Answer (score 1):

The **pattern match** should be:

```
  def tryMatch(x: Any): String = x match {
    case B() => "It's a B!"
    case C() => "It's a C!"
    case _ => "nope"
  }
```

because you want to match an **object** not an **type**.

if you want to match **Type**, you can use [TypeTag](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html), like:

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  def tryMatch[T](x: T)(implicit t: TypeTag[T]): String = x match {
    case _ if t.tpe =:= typeOf[B] => "It's a B!"
    case _ if t.tpe =:= typeOf[C] => "It's a C!"
    case _ => "nope"
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to match a type :) How would go to achieve that, please?

Comment: @sedulam, if you want to match type, you can use `TypeTag` to do it from scala 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain how to *fix* it, but not what the problem actually is. Each `case class` automatically has a companion `object` of the same name, so `case B` works just like `case None` when matching an `Option`: it is matched when `x` is equal to this object! If you replace `x: Any` with `x: A`, the compiler will tell you the match can't possibly work, because the object `B` is not an instance of `A`.